# Recover Whats-app database files (.crypt12)

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, data-recovery

Today I had to uninstall whats-app as my storage was 100% and all the apps were constantly crashing. I thought I would recover it later. However my file manager app ES file explorer offered me to delete app data which I accidentally okay-ed. Now I have only backup of Media files as of date and Google drive backup of a month back.

My phone is running Android Kitkat 4.4.4 and is not yet rooted.

Is there any way to restore msgstore****.crypt12 files from whatsapp databases?

I have all the whatsapp media but without messages it wont make much difference.

Please help.

P.S I have uninstalled whatsapp and have disabled sync so not new data could get overwritten to simplify recovery.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to restore `msgstore****.crypt12` files from whatsapp databases?

Yes, but you have to deactivate Google Drive sync. The only way is to remove Whatsapp from the authorized apps on this page:

https://myaccount.google.com/permissions

After that, locate the backups directory where the `.crypt12` files reside.

- Make a copy of the newest one that you would like to recover
- Call said copy exactly `msgstore.db.crypt12`
- Reinstall WhatsApp
- Wait until the setup asks you if you want to restore from the local backup (it won't suggest the one on Google Drive because you removed the authorization before)

Done!

Comment: Hi, I have deleted all the .crypt12 files from local storage. These is only one copy which is same as Google drive.

Comment: Wait, you deleted the contents of the SD card as well? O.o

Comment: Yes sadly.
I was thinking about this recovery tutorial but its way back from 2013
https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/general/guide-internal-memory-data-recovery-yes-t1994705

Comment: OK then the first step is taking out the SD card and doing a simple undelete with proper data recovery software. Then proceed as specified in the answer.

Comment: Which software do you suggest?
Most of them do not restore .crypt12 extensions. Only pics and videos can be recovered.

Comment: It seems you are already thinking about file carvers, while what you have to do is an undelete. Totally different things. The usual Testdisk might be a nice start.